# How to use SDURLCache and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

i'm beginner.i have a problem about SDURLCache and AFNetwoking.my code:

first,i setting sdurlcache in my appdelegate.m

```
self.cache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024 // 1 MB mem cache
                                           diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5 MB disk cache
                                               diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
self.cache.ignoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy = YES;
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:self.cache];
```

second,i used AFNetwoking+UIImageView in my tableCell:

```
 [cell.Image setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zhanweiSmall.png"]];
```

But picture not cache.if network is invalid,picture don't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IOS5 or above NSURLCache automatically saves responses to disk. So you don't need SDURLCache. See Peter's blog post for more info.

http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/